# Aurelia not updating value of object in array

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I have an array of objects called `options` and each option object has a boolean called `showThis`.  In my html, I am using a repeater over the `options` array, and I'm binding a checkbox to the `showThis` property.  I need to update the value of `showThis` in a method, so that I can trigger a save whenever the value changes.  However, absolutely no matter what I do, the value on screen will not update to reflect changing the value of `showThis` in my method.  Updating the value does nothing, and also using `splice()` does nothing.

Here is my html:

```
        <div class="row" repeat.for="option of options">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input click.delegate="checkChanged(option, $index)" checked.bind="option.showThis" type="checkbox">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            ${option.friendlyName}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my (current version) `checkChanged` method:

```
checkChanged(option, optionIndex){
    let self = this;
    option.showThis = !option.showThis;
    self.save();
}
```

I have also tried this version using `splice()`, with no change:

```
checkChanged(option, optionIndex){
    let self = this;
    self.options.splice(optionIndex, 1);
    option.showThis = !option.showThis;
    self.options.splice(optionIndex, 0, option);
    self.save();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`click.delegate` reverts the change after an `input` updates the value. To track changes you can add a `change.delegate` to the parent `div`.

```
<div change.delegate="save()">
  <div class="row" repeat.for="option of options">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input checked.bind="option.showThis" type="checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            ${option.friendlyName}
          </label>
        </div>
      <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will call `save` on `change` events fired by all elements, not just checkboxes. If this is undesirable you can move the delegate to specific elements.